# What tickets is Molly referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

In *Molly’s Game* (2017), Molly, a defendant, says to Charles, attorney:

> If I had a testimony that would lead to the conviction of a bad guy,
>   no one would have to coerce me into cooperating. But I don’t. I have
>   dish. So, my value to the prosecution is exactly the same as it is to
>   Hollywood. I’m here to ensure the New York Post covers the trial. I’m
>   here to sell tickets.

What tickets is Molly referring to?

Comment: It is pretty much a tongue in cheek analogy of this being a proverbial dog and pony show and they are going after me to "sell tickets" meaning drum up attention and get focus to said "show".